# C# read from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am using .net's Httpclient for the first time and finding it very hard. I have managed to call the server and receive response from it but stuck at reading from the response. Here is my code:

```
if (Method == HttpVerb.POST)
     response = client.PostAsync(domain, new StringContent(parameters)).Result;
else
     response = client.GetAsync(domain).Result;

if (response != null)
{
     var responseValue = string.Empty;

     Task task = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
     {
         var stream = t.Result;
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
         {
             responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
     });


     return responseValue;
}
```

responseValue has {} in it although the service is returning data. How should I fix the issue?

The project is in .Net 4.

Comment: you are using wcf service or web service? What is the status of reponse? responseValue.StatusCode = ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be `await`ing task before returning?

Comment: @PrinceT I am calling rest service

Comment: @DavidG where should I use await? well where ever I put await VS shows error that The await operator can only be used within an async method

Comment: @Haris As your function is not async, just use `Task.Wait()`, check my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are creating an asynchronous task but not waiting for it to complete before returning. This means your `responseValue` never gets set.

To fix this, before your return do this:

```
task.Wait();
```

So your function now looks like this:

```
if (Method == HttpVerb.POST)
     response = client.PostAsync(domain, new StringContent(parameters)).Result;
else
     response = client.GetAsync(domain).Result;

if (response != null)
{
     var responseValue = string.Empty;

     Task task = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
     {
         var stream = t.Result;
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
         {
             responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
     });

     task.Wait();

     return responseValue;
}
```

If you prefer to use `await` (which you possibly should), then you need to make the function this code is contained in `async`. So this:

```
public string GetStuffFromSomewhere()
{
    //Code above goes here

    task.Wait();
}
```

Becomes:

```
public async string GetStuffFromSomewhere()
{
    //Code above goes here

    await ...
}
```

Comment: nope still the same :(. however it works perfectly fine with WebRequest but the problem due to which I had to move to HttpClient was that with WebRequest I was unable to read cookies.

Comment: Is the function in the `ContinueWith` being executed?

Comment: yes it is being executed. noticed that t.Result.Length has 2 in it

Comment: I recommend reading this article to see how to use HttpClient: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: ok I got the data by changing domain and parameters. Domain was changed from `http://mydomain.com:38080/workshop/` to `http://mydomain.com:38080/workshop/rest/login` and parameters was changed from to `rest/login?username=usr&password=pwd` to `username=usr&password=pwd`. why is that? this will create problem of getting cookies as they are set at the domain level

Comment: Ah I see now. Well my answer still applies even though it's not a solution for you.

Comment: this means that I have to give complete address to rest controller. How will it affect the cookies (from where all this started). Because now when I get cookie from http://mydomain.com:38080/workshop/ I do not get anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(obj.Url);
                    HttpWebResponse response = null;

                    try
                    {
                        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
```

Comment: `WebRequest` should not be used when the newer `HttpClient` is available. Also, this doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: I was previously using WebRequest but I could not read cookies that is why moved to HttpClient. otherwise WebRequest works perfectly.